# (firebase-admin) Error: Error: Client is offline but its not?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline, firebase-admin

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import DataModel from "../types/firebase";

export class FirebaseManager {
  db = admin.database();

  constructor() {
    this.db = admin.database();
    if (this.db === undefined) {
      throw "cannot find database";
    }

    let data = this.db
      .ref(`/`)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
          throw "no database found :(";
        } else {
          let data = snapshot.val();
          try {
            let castedData = data as DataModel;
            console.log("Database successfully initialised!");
          } catch {
            throw "Data could not be casted properly during initialisation";
          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Hi, I have been working on a discord bot that needs firebase as a backend. however, when i initialise this class, calling the .get() function says `Error: Error: Client is offline` but I have been all the while online, anyone knows why? For reference, Im using the specific version  `"firebase-admin": "^9.11.1"`. If you would want to see all the code, `https://github.com/MaxiGames/MaxiGames.js/tree/firebase` here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, the problem was that we needed to follow the tutorial here `https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup` and set a environment variable, then use `admin.credential.applicationDefault()` as the credential parameter to the object that we input into he initialiseApp function. So, in the end the code should look like `admin.initializeApp({credential:admin.credential.applicationDefault(), databaseURL:"https://{your-project}-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"});`